# Coldfusion isDefined() in PHP

Tags: php, coldfusion

I am currently self learning PHP and would like to ask how do I write the following Coldfusion code, `isDefined()`, in PHP?

```
<cfif isDefined("name")>
...
</cfif>
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you had a look at the [`empty`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function?

Comment: Its not empty, I just made it empty so that its easier to look. Basically what I want is what is the equivalent of isDefined() in PHP?

Comment: What about [`isset`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)?

Comment: Thank you irundaia. I think that should be the one, I'll go read up about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function essentially has the same functionality:

```
isset($name);
```